# How do I create a new log on and password for minecraft pe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Trying to log onto a server but I forgot my password for Mojang. Every time I try to retrieve the password, nothing happens. How do I reset the game to create a new user Id and password?

Comment: "Nothing happens". What's meant to happen? Do you not receive any emails? No prompts to reset your password?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem for a while. Unfortunately, there is no way that i know of to make another P.E. account. Although you can just use a alternate email/gmail or relatives to just make a new one. I recommend just getting computer version if you want to play that bad. it is much better and more update and easier to use.